# I want to use 'LaTeX' syntax (MathJax) in my blog

Tags: javascript, html, equation, math-mode

I checked many instructions on how to set LaTeX in blogspot. I went to "add a gadget", "Configure HTML/JavaScript", and *[How to use LaTeX on blogspot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13865)*.

Then I posted this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
 extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
 jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
 tex2jax: {
     inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
     displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
 },
 "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
});
</script>
```

But nothing happened successfully.

What would be a screenshot of the process?

Comment: Unfortunately, mathjax doesn't use the TeX engine at all. This question is therefore out of the scope of this site.

Comment: This looks like a MathJaX configuration problem which isn't therefore related to TeX itself.  It is therefore off-topic for this site where questions are meant to be about TeX.  You could try it on StackOverflow.

Comment: It works for me, make sure you've placed the code between `<head>` and `</head>`.
A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the extra comma after the `displayMath` delimiters. These extra commas often confuse Internet Explorer, so if you are using Internet Explorer as your browser, that might be the issue.